# Why get_queried_object() return wrong taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here my code for taxonomy industries of Event custom post type:

```
 // Add new "Industries" taxonomy to Events
register_taxonomy('industries', 'event', array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'Industries', 'taxonomy general name', 'sb_theme' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Industries', 'taxonomy singular name', 'my_theme' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Industry', 'my_theme' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Industries', 'my_theme' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Industry', 'my_theme' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Industry:', 'my_theme' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Industry', 'my_theme' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Industry', 'my_theme' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Industry', 'my_theme' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Industry', 'my_theme' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Industries', 'my_theme' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'industries',
        'with_front' => false, 
        'hierarchical' => true 
    ),
));
```

Another taxonomy of Event:

```
// Add new "Type" taxonomy to Events
    register_taxonomy('type-events', 'event', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Types', 'taxonomy general name', 'my_theme' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Types', 'taxonomy singular name', 'my_theme' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Type', 'my_theme' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Types', 'my_theme' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Type', 'my_theme' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Type:', 'my_theme' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Type', 'my_theme' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Type', 'my_theme' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Type', 'my_theme' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Type', 'my_theme' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Types', 'my_theme' ),
        ),
        // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'type-events', 
            'with_front' => false, 
            'hierarchical' => true
        ),
    ));
```

And in dashboard admin, i create a new Industries taxonomy: test-indus, here is image of my dashboard admin [image: Industries taxonomy in admin]

I get posts of industrie taxonomy by this code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'showposts' => '12',
        'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                         'taxonomy' => $queried_object->taxonomy,
                         'terms' => $queried_object->slug,
                         'field' => 'slug'
                        )
                   ),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'paged' => $paged,
        );
$loop = get_posts( $args );
var_dump($queried_object);
```

And here is result when i var_dump($queried_object) [image: Result var_dump]

I don't understand why $queried_object->taxonomy return to 'type-events'?? The truth it should be 'industries'?

I just a newbie, plz help me, thank so much :)

Comment: In which page is included the `get_queried_object()` function?

Comment: @andreivictor: It's taxonomy.php

Comment: Try to use a more specific template, like: `taxonomy-industries-test-indus.php` or `taxonomy-industries.php`. See the template hierarchy for custom taxonomies here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/#custom-taxonomy.

Comment: I cant do it because i use this function for all taxonomy. I have 4 taxonomy for Envents post type, they are use the same function :(

Comment: sorry, right now I don't have the necesary time to come up with a more detailed or advanced idea.

Comment: thank you so much @andreivictor